# yeoman can't be used on cygwin

Tags: node.js, cygwin

I've installed Cygwin_x86,NodeJS 0.8.4,with node modules:Yeoman,Grunt-cli.but when I use yo,这CLI returns

```
qiaofu@taobaou3- /cygdrive/c/workspace/test
$ yo
[?] ==========================================================================
We're constantly looking for ways to make yo better!
May we anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time?
More info: yeoman.io/insight.html & http://yeoman.io
========================================================================== (Y/n)
qiaofu@taobaou3- /cygdrive/c/workspace/test
```

but I just CANNOT Type Y or n.